# How could I update a youtube video via php api?

Tags: php, api, youtube

I will update a video with a code like this:

```
$headers = array("PUT /feeds/api/users/default/uploads/VIDEOID HTTP/1.1",
"Host: gdata.youtube.com",
"Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=".$authvalue,
"GData-Version: 2",
"X-GData-Key: key=KEY",
"Content-length: ".strlen($data),
"Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8");
$curl = curl_init("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads/VIDEOID");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$returnxxx = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $returnxxx;
```

I've generate a valide authvalue (tested it -> ok). But it shows:

> invalid uri

Thanks for helping!

Comment: your headers are defining a PUT, but you're setting curl to do a POST. for put, you need to use CURLOPT_PUT.

Comment: @Kiro Coneski No - I will update / edit the video information -> see here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_updating_and_deleting_videos Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marc B Thanks for your hint!
I've used `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');` instead of the `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`!